# Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom not found when compiling Visual Studio 13 Lightswitch Project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-lightswitch, localdb, lightswitch-2013

I have an out of the box Lightswitch project, the only changes are adding a simple table with one string row, changing the project to look for localdb v12, and adding some JS files into the project that are from the aspnetcdn and this is an offline environment.

So, when trying to compile I get this error:

```
An exception occurred when building the database for the application.
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom,         
Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one 
of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.            
C:\Program Files\(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\LightSwitch\v4.5\Microsoft.LightSwitch.targets
```

My guess is the issue has to do with using LocalDB 12, as the error is for ScriptDom v=11.  But how do I verify or change this?

The environment is Windows 08 R2 Server w/ SQL Server 14.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

How did you change the solution to look for LocalDb v12? I believe the correct way is by using Tools -> Options -> Database Tools -> Data Connections to change the instance name.